# Instagram-like stories for a B2B eCommerce site?

Tags: e-commerce, b2b

we have a B2B eCommerce site and we were thinking about creating instagram-like stories on our site to help promote new products/vendors/offers.

I saw this functionality implemented in http://faces.com/ for a brief time ([here is a video of what it looked like](https://i.imgur.com/K4sOVDw.mp4)) and that's what inspired us to think about it.

does it fit a B2B site to have instagram-like stories?

Answer (score 1):

There is no yes or no to this question. It depends largely on what your site should do and what your users need. Here are some questions you should investigate:

- What informations do your users need?
- What is the main device your users use your site (on b2b sites it could (but doesn't have to be) probably be desktop instead of mobile)?
- How important is it to your users to know about new products? Are they willing to go through the stories?
- How important is the time factor? Would your users prefer a faster way to receive an overview on your new products?

These are only a few questions you should actually ask your users to come to a conclusion if this is the right way to go.